# Issues with wireless adapter, hard crashes

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter, mediatek

I've had issues with my wireless adapter and ubuntu on this machine ever since I got it. Usually after a period of inactivity, the wireless adapter will disappear completely and the only thing that seems to reliably bring it back is disabling the internal battery and rebooting. Sometimes the wireless adapter disappears and the rest of the system keeps functioning, but a lot of the time this will also lead to a hard crash a few seconds later.

This is on a Lenovo Thinkbook 13, Ubuntu 23.10.

```
sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e
Jan 22 12:24:55 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: driver own failed
Jan 22 12:24:56 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jan 22 12:24:57 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: driver own failed
Jan 22 12:24:58 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jan 22 12:24:59 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: driver own failed
Jan 22 12:25:01 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jan 22 12:25:02 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: driver own failed
Jan 22 12:25:03 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jan 22 12:25:04 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: driver own failed
Jan 22 12:25:05 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: Timeout for driver own
Jan 22 12:25:06 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: driver own failed
Jan 22 12:25:08 (thiscomp) kernel: mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: Timeout for driver own
```

```
lspci
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
```

```
uname -a
Linux (thiscomp) 6.7.0-060700-generic #202401072033 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Jan  7 20:43:59 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"uaifai"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 12:A7:93:23:08:68   
          Bit Rate=288.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:14   Missed beacon:0
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `iwconfig`

Comment: Looks like there are known stability issues with the MT7922 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286981 that are likely to be fixed in a more recent kernel (this site suggests a manual patch). You could try installing a different kernel, if offered in 23.10 (I don't have a copy to check) but you may have to purchase a USB WiFi adaptor until the patch gets included in the Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Good to know! I have been periodically upgrading the kernel, hoping it will get added and magically fix everything but that hasn't happened yet. I will look into that manual patch or a USB wifi adapter. Thanks